# Triangle isn't rendering correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering, render

I'm trying to render a 2D triangle that rotates after time but it is not rendering correctly. It starts with an normal triangle but than transforms itself into someting that i cant explain at all. Can someone explain what is going on here?

What i mean as a video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRXtp.jpg

[image] ... [image] ... [image]

Here is how im building my scene:

```
void Camera::UpdateCamera(struct Level* lvl) {

    Shader::SetShaderProgram(lvl->shader.GetShaderID());
    glBindVertexArray(lvl->model.getVAO());

    //model scene
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::rotate(model, (float)glfwGetTime() * glm::radians(50.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    //view scene
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    view = glm::lookAt(lvl->cam.m_cameraPos, lvl->cam.m_cameraPos + lvl->cam.cameraFront, lvl->cam.cameraUp);

    //projection scene
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    if (lvl->cam.changeProjection)
    {
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), (float)800 / (float)600, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        lvl->cam.changeProjection = false;
    }

    //Set scene uniforms for vertex shader
    Shader::setMat4(lvl->shader.GetShaderID(), "model", model);
    Shader::setMat4(lvl->shader.GetShaderID(), "view", view);
    Shader::setMat4(lvl->shader.GetShaderID(), "projection", projection);

}
```

Here are my drawing commands:

```
glUseProgram(m_shaderID);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Here is my vertex shader code:

```
#version 450 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = model * view * projection *vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: It has to be `gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` call. As a result you draw the rotated triangle over the previous one.

Comment: You just made me so incredible happy. I was searching for this error for a whole week. Thanks a lot Yakov Galka!